# filtering in typescript without a type guard

Tags: typescript

I have created [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ts=4.0.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAClC8UDeUB2BDAthAXFAzsAE4CWqA5lAL4DcAUHQMYD2qhsANgK7lmu6wEyNFgEByfmOpNW7GN16pgAd2Z44iFBmx4xK5lKoy2wTjzLAAFkQgCNw7eKs2Ih43IVkAZsy5F1Qlqiuj5+bu6mJPgAIhAAbhAczGDYSkJe6Bz4EPQRUFH2ABToeOioIACUpfn4gvAAfFCgkMxeUOgI8IgSAEYAVhCMwGIMLCaw+ACM6gDaALpCM-LmqPwANDWxCUkpEGkAZPtmivobUVuJyammh8cW1rYby4qhRHMAdF4kHMAQRIUAIWYzA4EDKFQYAHpIU1LNBWBwQFBlOgkQBJKCMMoEWxNZhQTDoADW0BIplURCJeRg+AATLMFoglp5VqgIGcYvFLrsDkdnhZVByLjtrlBbvylA92XdUK8Pl8fn9CgUKkA) to illustrate the problem and here is the code:

```js
type P = { name: string };

const Pluginone: P = { name: 'one' }
const Plugintwo: P = { name: 'two' }
const Pluginthree: P = { name: 'three' }
const Pluginfour: P = { name: 'four' }

const isDevelopment = false;

const isP = (a: any): a is P => typeof a === 'object'

const Ps1: P[] = [Pluginone, isDevelopment && Plugintwo, isDevelopment && Pluginthree, Pluginfour].filter(Boolean)

// the only way I can see to make it work
const Ps2: P[] = [Pluginone, isDevelopment && Plugintwo, isDevelopment && Pluginthree, Pluginfour].filter(isP)
```

Basically, `.filter(Boolean)` does not work but creating an explicit type guard does work which is a pity.

Is there a way to filter without having to create the type guard?

Comment: Nope, this is how it works, you need a user-defined type guard. :(

Comment: I think type guard is for this purpose. But you can use something like this: .filter(function (p) { return p != true && p != false; });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess TypeScript doesn't currently guarantee that `Ps1` will end up as an array of type `P[]` because that's a potential pitfall for a lot of developers. I imagine it can probably be implied from the code, but it's very easy to wind up with different object types in the array at runtime. They added `is` for a reason. You can write it inline though, but that's just a styling difference:

```js
const Ps1: P[] = [Pluginone, false].filter((i): i is P => Boolean(i))
```